# ExtendedFloatingActionButton Color Resource identifiers unavailable

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, material-components-android

I'm trying to get the background, foreground (icon and text) and ripple colours for `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` but the Color Resource identifiers are inaccessible. The Color Resources I'm trying to obtain are:

```
Resource.Color.m3_fab_efab_background_color_selector
Resource.Color.m3_fab_efab_foreground_color_selector
Resource.Color.m3_efab_ripple_color_selector
```

Using `ContextCompat.GetColorStateList(context, Resource.Color.m3_fab_efab_background_color_selector)`, for example, just doesn't compile as the Resource identifier is not found. The compile time error I get is, "'Resource.Color' does not contain a definition for 'm3_fab_efab_background_color_selector'".

I'm using `Xamarin.Android` and I have the latest "AndroidX Material" package(s) installed. The "Xamarin.Google.Android.Material", in particular, which is the bindings library for the "com.google.android.material" package.

How do I go about obtaining those values without direct access to the Resource identifiers?

Also, is there a reason as to why those Resource identifiers are not available?

I found those Resource identifiers in the "material-components" [source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/res/values/styles.xml#L224).

Comment: How about using this `AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.Color.m3_fab_efab_background_color_selector)` method.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Thanks for your response. The problem I have is the Resource identifier is just inaccessible. So, I just get a compile time error, "'Resource.Color' does not contain a definition for 'm3_fab_efab_background_color_selector'".

Comment: I found that the resource belongs to material-components com.google.android.material.material. I thought you properly installed the wrong package or the package you did not install.

Comment: Hi @GuangyuBai-MSFT, the "Xamarin.Google.Android.Material" NuGet package which is a bindings library for "com.google.android.material" is installed and up to date in my project. Is it possible to the check bindings library and see if the source contains a reference to those Resource identifiers? It may be that the bindings library itself has somehow missed them.